# Can I import super:: from a mod that's inside a fn?

Tags: rust

I realise that this is an extremely odd thing to do but I'm writing a macro I'd like to be usable in as many places as possible. Take the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f06853e96bdd94cb028cc9b63bc986b):

```
mod outer {

    struct OuterTestStruct {}
    
    fn do_thing() {

        struct InnerTestStruct {}
        
        mod inner {
            use super::OuterTestStruct;
            use super::InnerTestStruct;
        }
    }
    
}
```

This doesn't compile because of the `use super::InnerTestStruct` line. But the `use super::OuterTestStruct` line works fine, so my assumption here is that `super` skips over the `fn` context and goes straight to the parent `mod`.

Is there any way I can get a reference to `InnerTestStruct` from inside `mod inner`? Especially without knowing any context beforehand (i.e. imagine a macro invocation inside `fn do_thing()`, it isn't going to know it's inside a fn)

Comment: You can put `mod` inside an `fn`?

Comment: When you say "doesn't compile" it helps to include the *exact* errors you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `super` will refer to the encompassing *module*, not the function scope.

> Is there any way I can get a reference to `InnerTestStruct` from inside `mod inner`?

There is no path that can name `InnerTestStruct` as far as I'm aware.

---

Since you mention macros specifically, the [Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/macros.html#item-macros-work-anywhere-that-items-are-allowed-c-anywhere) warns against this exact case:

> #### Item macros work anywhere that items are allowed
>
> Rust allows items to be placed at the module level or within a tighter scope like a function. Item macros should work equally well as ordinary items in all of these places. The test suite should include invocations of the macro in at least the module scope and function scope.
>
> As a simple example of how things can go wrong, this macro works great in a module scope but fails in a function scope.
>
> ```
> macro_rules! broken {
>     ($m:ident :: $t:ident) => {
>         pub struct $t;
>         pub mod $m {
>             pub use super::$t;
>         }
>     } }
>
> broken!(m::T); // okay, expands to T and m::T
>
> fn g() {
>     broken!(m::U); // fails to compile, super::U refers to the containing module not g
> }
> ```

The only fix I know is to introduce another module:

```
mod outer {
    struct OuterTestStruct {}

    fn do_thing() {
        mod middle { // <----------------
            struct InnerTestStruct {}

            mod inner {
                use super::super::OuterTestStruct;
                use super::InnerTestStruct;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is [issue #79260](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79260) filed for this problem. One poster suggests using an unused inner function instead to introduce a scope.