# Access type from parent scope from module inside function

Tags: rust

Asking mostly out of curiosity, I don't have a use case for this.

Reading the Rust Reference, I noticed that it is apparently legal to define any kind of items within a function. According to the reference:

> the item's path name ... is private to the enclosing item (in the case of functions)

Suppose the following code, where we define a type and a module within a function:

```rs
pub fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Foo;

    mod module {
        pub fn function() {
            println!("{:?}", Foo);
        }
    }

    module::function();
}
```

Is it possible to reference the `Foo` type defined in the `main` function from within the `module` module?

Currently I get the following compile error:

```
  |
7 |             println!("{:?}", Foo);
  |                              ^^^ not found in this scope
```

Comment: Seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752423/can-i-import-super-from-a-mod-thats-inside-a-fn) is closely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [issue #79260](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79260). As far as I know there is no way to refer to `Foo` inside `function()`.